# iOS avplayer voice memo trim style scrubber

Tags: ios, video, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer as the interface for a video editing application.

Is there a scrubber that's in the similar style as the Voice Memos Trim Memo scrubber (but for video)?

[image: Audio Trim]

Answer (score 0):

[BJRangeSlider](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bjrangesliderwithprogress) is a control that accomplishes the same goal (albeit with a different UI), but I assume subclassing won't be too hard.